# Change xml item node value

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm trying to change the text `Cart Subtotal` to be `Basket Subtotal` but upon checking this text is within the `checkout_index_index.xml` and is under the referencontainer content. I want to modify the value of this and upon checking this is the node that is responsible for this

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.root" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Basket Subtotal</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

When I tried to put this to my checkout_index_index.xml it broke the view and was not loading. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to reference to `checkout.root` block?

Your `checkout_index_index.xml` should become like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Basket Subtotal</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: dude you saved me a lot. Forgot I should be using referenceblock. Thanks a lot it worked.